# Combinations of strings from data

Tags: combinations

So, we have data. a little big data.
example.

```
0 -> [a, b]
1 -> c
2 -> [d, e, f]
3 -> [g, h]
4 -> k
5 -> l
```

we need to combine each of this values. for this example output will be a lot of variants.

```
acdgkl
acdhkl
acegkl
acehkl
acfgkl
acfhkl
bcdgkl
bcdhkl
bcegkl
bcehkl
bcfgkl
bcfhkl
```

Quetion: what is this action procedure of combinating values called?)
and how to realize it :)
THX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process which turns something like

```
[['a','b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['k'], ['l']]
```

into the sequence

```
[['a','c','d','g','k','l'],
 ['a','c','d','h','k','l'],
 ...
```

is called taking the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).  I don't think there's a name for the specific process of also concatenating the result when they're strings.  (Also note that I've made each term a list, even if it's a list of one element, rather than alternating between lists (`['a','b']`) and scalars (`'c'`)).

This is a common enough process that many languages have built-in support, e.g. [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> source = [['a','b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['k'], ['l']]
>>> outputs = product(*source)
>>> for out in outputs:
...     print(out)
...     
('a', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'k', 'l')
('a', 'c', 'd', 'h', 'k', 'l')
('a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'k', 'l')
('a', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'k', 'l')
('a', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'k', 'l')
('a', 'c', 'f', 'h', 'k', 'l')
('b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'k', 'l')
('b', 'c', 'd', 'h', 'k', 'l')
('b', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'k', 'l')
('b', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'k', 'l')
('b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'k', 'l')
('b', 'c', 'f', 'h', 'k', 'l')
```

Even if the language you're using doesn't support this natively, it's straightforward to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Believe you are looking for [Permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) and [Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).
Try using nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the comment of DSM (as I don't have enough points)

But if you want to concatenate the lists and print them as strings use

```
print ''.join(out)
```

instead of
    print